# Cannot Create Spldoublylinkedlist

Tags: java, php, collections, linked-list

I am a rookie PHP developer and have recently migrated from a Java developer. For my initial tutorials, I have started executing sample, demo PHP programs available on the web.

I am currently practicing programs on PHP collections provided to us by the PHP framework and the SplDoubleLinkedList in particular.

I have a class named Awards where I am trying to create a field, _dll of the type, SplDoubleLinkedList.

The source code of my Awards class is given as follows:

*Awards.php*

```
    <?php

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     * This is the Award class
     *
     * @author Razor
     */
    class Award {
        $_dll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();

        function executeCode() {
            $_dll->push(2);
            $_dll->push(3);
            $_dll->unshift(5);

            var_dump($_dll);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that despite copy-pasting the code from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.construct.php), the compiler is returning me a syntax error on the line where I have declared the `$_dll` field. The error is, `unexpected: variable $_dll. expected: function, const, use, var, }, VAR_COMMENT, static, abstract, final, private, protected, public`

Can anyone please tell me where exactly am I going wrong? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring the property, you need to specify whether it's `public`, `private` or `protected` (or some of the other options, but these are the most likely). And you can't assign `new SplDoublyLinkedList()` at declaration, so you need to handle that initialization in the constructor.

```
class Award {
    protected $_dll;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $_dll = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. That was so stupid of me to not have noticed that. LOL =D